# Can software under the "BSD 2-Clause License" be uploaded to PyPI?

Tags: licensing, python, bsd-license

I have a Python library licensed under the [BSD 2-Clause License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause). This library was created by another person, who, I think, basically stopped maintaining it. For this reason, I want to pick it up and put it on Github, so that I can eventually promote its maintenance.

Can software licensed under the "BSD 2-Clause" license be uploaded to Github and PyPI, even if who uploads that software is not the creator?

Comment: Note external services like libraries.io will declare the software as BSD-3-Clause, as PyPI use an ambiguous "OSI Approved :: BSD License". Make clear in README or with a LICENSE file it's a BSD-2-Clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BSD license allows you to do anything you want with the code as long as you include the relevant copyright notices and license information, and pypi has no specific restrictions against the uploading of code with BSD-style licenses.